# Random behavior with worksheet

Tags: sage

Consider this simple creation of list of list of list

```
x = [[[None]*2 for n in range(4)] for j in range(9)]; x
```

it printed the object and then suddenly doing the same exact code doesn't print anything. Tried `del x` and doing the code again, but no luck. doing `type(x)` doesn't print anything neither.

There's no error message.

I actually have the same problem with some other lines of code, including some that print different results with the same code executed at short notice.

Is this a problem of the worksheet or a Sage problem? It is very annoying as you never know if you did something right or not.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Can you say exactly where you were using Sage Math?  (Sage notebook, which version, Sage Math Cloud, etc.)  The only thing I can think is that perhaps you had a timeout on your worksheet.

Comment: Sorry. Using notebook, Sagemath 7.2, localhost.